# Parsing lower than symbol with nodejs and cheerio

Tags: node.js, parsing, cheerio

I'm trying to parse a numeric data that includes a lower than symbol like this:
< 0.003
Having this original tags in the document to parse;

```
<TD VALIGN=TOP><P ALIGN=LEFT>
  <FONT FACE="Helvetica">
    <SPAN STYLE="Font-Size: 12pt"><0.0003</SPAN>
  </FONT>
</TD>
```

The problem is that cheerio handle it as an unclosed html tag and close it generating a tag with the name of the value like this:

```
<td valign="TOP">
    <p align="LEFT">
        <font face="Helvetica">
            <span style="Font-Size: 12pt">
                <0.0003< span=""></0.0003<>
            </span>
        </font>
    </p>
</td>
```

I've tried with no luck the option decodeEntities:true

How can I correctly get the value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing this is because a bare `<` is an illegal character as far as HTML is concerned which will cause a great amount of hurt for cheerio, which expects its input to be well-defined.

(While you might imagine this *should* cause browsers to fail to render the page, the ["official" HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) suggests that browsers should be as forgiving as they can be with "badly formed" input.)

One way to fix this problem would be to run your content through a regular expression to correctly convert all bare `<` (those that appear before  to their correct HTML entity: '<' as in:

```
// assumes the page content is kept in this var.
var content = '<p>1 < 2<br/>3</p>2 < 3'; 

content=content.replace(/<([^<>]+(?:<|$))/g,'&lt;$1');
```

will produce:

```
<p>1 &lt; 2<br/>3</p> 2 &lt; 3
```

The regular expression is:

```
<            -- literal '<'
(            -- start capture group #1
  [^<>]+     -- one or more characters except literal '<' or '>'
  (?:        -- start non-capturing group
    <        -- literal '<'
  |          -- OR
    $        -- end of content
  )          -- end of non-capturing group
)            -- end of capture group #1
```

Adding the `/g` flag to the regular expression causes it to be run as many times as the pattern matches the content.

Comment: I'd also note that bare '<' characters are not the only problem in your example HTML which appears to have been generated using a _very_ archaic understanding of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/540) in the `github` regarding the custom option for parsing the html. Expected in future.

#### Work Around:

```
var $ = cheerio.load('<TD VALIGN=TOP>kk<P ALIGN=LEFT><FONT FACE="Helvetica"><SPAN STYLE="Font-Size: 12pt">>0.0003</SPAN></FONT></TD>');

$("*").each(function(i, elem) {
    console.log($(elem)[0].name);
});
```

`$(elem)[0].name` will log all the tag name, You can use some regex to filter out the number.

`Note:` Problem is only for `<` symbol. For `>` symbol it will parse as `&gt;`